# What exactly should I set as JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables, openjdk, tomcat

I am trying to make Tomcat 7 working with Eclipse, and I am not sure if my JAVA_HOME is correct.

```
~$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

And there is no such catalog!

I only have:

```
~$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Is my JAVA_HOME correct?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you almost got it. You can use this command to detect where your jvm is located.

> whereis jvm

I have same setting and I believe you can point on either dir in JAVA_HOME as java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 is a weak link to other( see man for ln).

Ah and Answer "it is not correct! Take one from pwd command."

Answer (score 0):

#### Your `JAVA_HOME` setting is fine.

The file `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` should be a symlink pointing to the JRE and is provided by the `default-jre-headless` package. This package is required for a regular Java (default JRE) installation of Java in Ubuntu. Apparently you removed this symlink, removed the individual package or something like that, or, you installed the JRE in an alternative matter.

I'd suggest to make sure you install the JRE again with the specific package as well.

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre default-jre-headless
```

And to verify the correct JVM is selected as default Java:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws # optional, java web plugin
```

Then you should be all fine with the default settings.